# NSTextView compatibilty class in Linux

Tags: linux, gtk

Is there any class in Linux system which is compatible to NSTextView in cocoa framework.

Comment: iSight: You should retag the question about the API you are using (GTK? KDE? GNUstep? Something else?), not the API you are coming from. Until you do, you will be getting more answers from Cocoa programmers than from GTK/KDE/GNUstep/whatever programmers.

Comment: @Peter How can i retag my question

Comment: iSight: Click on the edit link.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using GNUstep, Linux doesn't include *any* Objective-C classes, much less NSTextView. If you are using GNUstep, then NSTextView would be the obvious answer.

Linux does have its own APIs for creating text entry controls, but they're very different from the ones in OpenStep/Cocoa.

Comment: Can you please get me the link for it with some sample example.

Comment: @iSight: Some sample code using the GtkTextView API: http://www.bravegnu.org/gtktext/ — But I mean, I think you'll want to learn GTK rather than just which API is roughly equivalent to NSTextView.